# How to draw graphics object in windows 8 winRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How i can draw hand free graphic objects in windows 8, like paint can. I implemented such things in windows phone with Inkpresenter. But in winRT it seems that no such items are present. So i decided to use WritablebitmapEX, but idont know hot to implement this in windows 8. No sample code present in the downloading site. please any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/282a211e-e3bf-4184-8868-40208aa596dd

Answer (score 2):

there is a good quickstart page on the Microsoft Site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh974457.aspx